# Cannot replace an image by replacing the image files in Finder

Tags: xcode, resources

I would like to update some images (gif) in my application. After replacing the gif files in the folder, I build the application and run it; the images shown in simulator are not updated. I tried to "Clear all target" and then re-built the application; the new images can be shown in the simulator.

Does it mean the images will be successfully updated in the devices which have installed the older version of the application? Should I modify the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to **"Replace"** those image by the same names as in the earlier build.In this way even if your app is in the App Store, after submitting your update with the new images having the same names can be updated easily.

No need to modify your code.

Comment: Thanks :)
Actually the names of the new set of images are same as the old images. Then I build and run the app in simulator, but the images shown are not updated (old images shown although I deleted them in the finder).

Comment: You need to delete the old build from the simulator to see the new images,and you don't need to worry about that in case of device build as your build is also updated when a new update is pushed in App Store.

Comment: Do you mean if I am able to see the new images in my simulator/devices, then my customers can also update the images by installing the new version of app in App Store?

Comment: I mean to say that if you replace images with same names and push the update on App Store,when a user having previous version of your app downloads your update,then your new images would be reflected.Hope your doubt is clear now.